# Inappropriate class cast in ImapMailReceiver

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In [ImapMailReceiver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mail/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/ImapMailReceiver.java) there are casts to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder and com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage. When upgrading our app from spring integrations 2.0.1 to something newer (because of a bug in 2.0.1) our app now fails at runtime with a ClassCastException because we are not using the Message impl from com.sun, we are using something custom. Can this cast be removed?

Edit, here is the stack trace running with 2.2.3:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail
       at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:67)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: our.custom.IMAPMessage cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.searchForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:235)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:59)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Provide, please, the StackTrace on the matter. The cust to `com.sun.mail.imap` has been here even before `2.0.1`

Comment: Can you explain further? Show a StackTrace? Even in 2.0.1 we asserted that the folder was an `IMAPFolder` and the messages are obtained from that. Did you subclass `IMAPFolder` but not `IMAPMessage`?

Comment: OK. Show, please, your custom code, which build that `our.custom.IMAPMessage`. Does it really an issues for you to extend from `IMAPMessage` ?

Comment: Thanks. The code is internal legacy code and due for a refactor so perhaps extending IMAPMessage would work, though I gave it a quick spin and see some non-trivial things off the bat which would need to be reworked. It would be helpful to know if you agree these casts should be removed or not (and when) for our project planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments to question.

Please go ahead and open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll take a look. Even better, [make a contribution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Bear in mind it will likely cause issues - such as where we have to cast in order to set the `peek` property...

```
((IMAPMessage) message).setPeek(true);
```